# How do I get access too variables in multi-dimentional sass maps

Tags: arrays, sass

## Applying multi-dimentional sass maps as colors

Trying to store my colors in a sass map for easy use. But I would like to store variations of the color like dark and light. below is an example of my map

```
$button-colors: (
  'red': (
    'base': #ff0000,
    'light': #ff1a1a,
    'dark': #800000
  ),
  'blue': (
    'base': #2457DD,
    'light': #3399ff,
    'dark': #003366
  ),
  'green': (
    'base': #00cc00,
    'light': #4DFF57,
    'dark': #187F09
  )
);
```

But I'm not sure how to apply these colors to my classes.

I can do it with an `@each` loop but if I only want a single color for something I don't know how to get it. Here is an example of a class I would like to use a specific color.

```
.supa-class{
    color: //$button-colors.red.base;
}
```

## Question

How do I get access to the colors in the 2nd array?

## Possible duplicate

The question and answers on possible duplicate are for an iteration over the array to apply styles to multiple elements. In this question I wish to know how to retrieve one single value from my sass-map and apply it to an attribute. i.e. the duplicate does not answer my question.

Comment: How about reading the first line of the oldest answer?  Did you even *read* them?  Or did you just see a loop and ignored the rest?

Comment: @cimmanon my apologies, you were right. The final answer is exactly what I was looking for, it has no thumbs up and is not accepted as correct that's why I skimmed over it. thanks for pointing it out.